# Embedding Text File (Link to text file) in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, mht

I have been trying to embed a text file like we can do with Word files.

1. Go to Insert >> Object
2. Check the box which says "Insert as a link"

At this instance, there is no option for text files. I can achieve this with Word files but not with txt and mht files.

I need to embed those in my Word document and do not want to send a dozen files across along with the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, text (.txt) files and .mht files are not 'objects' in the sense of what Microsoft Office considers to be an embeddable object.

Answer (score 11):

I'm unsure which version of Word you're using, but here's how you can do it in 2010:

1. Go to the `Insert` tab on the ribbon
2. In the `Text` section of the `Insert` tab, choose the drop-down option beside the `Object` button
3. Choose `Text from File`
4. Navigate to your text file and select it *with one mouse click* (do not insert it yet)
5. Press the drop-down on the `Insert` button, and select `Insert as Link`

Your .txt file is now inserted as a field. After you update the file, click the field in your word document and press `F9` to see the new text. To update all fields at once, select the whole document (`Ctrl+A`) then press `F9`.

**Alternate method:**

1. Place your cursor where you want the file inserted
2. Press `Ctrl+F9`
3. Type `{ INCLUDETEXT "C:\\path\\to\\file.txt" \c AnsiText  \* MERGEFORMAT }`. *Do not* type the brackets. *Do* type the double-backslashes.
4. Press F9

Note that `\* MERGEFORMAT` is only necessary if you want the field to assume the formatting of the surrounding text.

Comment: Is there a way to insert a relative link?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. I suppose you've tried entering a relative path using the 'Alternate method'? I'm unlikely to be much use though, sorry, I don't currently have access to a machine with Word installed. Perhaps you could ask a new question, referencing this question. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I tried the alternate method and a solution from a website which didn't work. So I created this question as you suggested: https://superuser.com/q/1436274/549571

Comment: This works in Office 2013. It gets around the fact that MS Office doesn't consider text files as "link-able" when using the traditional Paste Special option.

Answer (score 1):

A simple copy/paste of the text files should do the trick.

Locate the text files on your computer, select the specific files, right click your mouse and select copy, go to your word document, and paste in there, the text files will be embedded.
This worked for me in Word 2007

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'insert as a link' and then also check the 'Display as a icon' option, and choose the TXT file icon from the following location:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\shell32.dll
```