# Embedding text from file via a relative link to the file in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/637632/549571) describes how to embed a text file via a link to the file in MS Word as follows:

1. Place your cursor where you want the file inserted
2. Press `Ctrl+F9`
3. Type `{ INCLUDETEXT "C:\\path\\to\\file.txt" \c AnsiText }`. *Do not* type the brackets. *Do* type the double-backslashes.
4. Press F9

I would like to know if it is possible to use a relative link. In the example the link is absolute.

I have tried using the filename field (`{INCLUDETEXT  "{FILENAME \\p}\\..\\..\\header.txt"}`) as suggested at [www.msofficeforums.com](http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38722-word-fields-relative-paths-external-files.html), but it didn't wrok for me using MS Office Pro 2016.

Comment: As posted, you have two backslashes before the "p" switch in the FILENAME field and you have and extra "dot dot backslash backslash" sequence in the path name that probably should not be there.